# Se pueden combinar dos base de datos en una misma vista yii framework 1.1

Tags: yii

Hola que tan ? tengo una duda,estoy comenzando a aprender yii 1.1. Por razones laborales comencé con esta version. Mi problema es el siguiente y quiero saber si es posible hacerlo.
Tengo dos bases de datos distintas en el mismo servidor (localhost). 
Lo que necesito hacer es mostrar en una view una grilla con unos ciertos datos de una de las base de datos y otra grilla (en la misma View) con otros datos de la otra base de datos. 
Tengo modelos y el metodo getConnection() en active record para que seleccione las dos bases pero no se como agregar los datos de esa segunda grilla que contiene informacion de la otra base de datos. 
Espero me puedan guiar estoy muy perdido y frustrado de muchos intentos fallidos.

Saludos!

Comment: Cual es tu error, debes definir las dos conexiones en tu config, luego asignar la conexion a tu modelo que parece ser lo has hecho, entonces no deberías tener problema.